# how can i implement a parse server cloud code function to write in firebase

Tags: parse-cloud-code

How can i implement a cloud Code function on back4app parse server to write data on firebase realtime.
follow my first approach:

thanks for any help.

```
const fb = require('firebase');// not working
const Produto = Parse.Object.extend("Produto");
const Fornecedor = Parse.Object.extend("Fornecedor");
const Users = Parse.Object.extend("Users");

Parse.Cloud.define("CriarUsu", async(request)=>{
  const user = new Parse.User();
  const fb = new fb(); // not working
  return("tudo ok")
});
```

Comment: Are you facing any message errors about that? Have you installed the module in your package.json?

Comment: package.json{
  "dependencies": {
        "firebase":"9.13.0"
  }
}

Comment: {
 "code": 141,
 "error": "Invalid function: \"CriarUsu\""
}

Comment: If you create a hello function like this: 

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", (request) => {
        console.log(fb);
 return("Hello world!");
});

Are you able to see the expected return?